# Why Would You Import CSS Files in a JS File?

Tags: javascript

I'm really confused by [this file](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct/blob/master/src/index.js) **index.js**:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import createHash from 'sha.js';
import Evaporate from 'evaporate';
import SparkMD5 from 'spark-md5';

import './css/bootstrap-progress.css';
import './css/styles.css';
...
```

Why would you import a `.css` file in a `.js` file? I've never seen this before. Is this common? What does it allow you to do?

Comment: It's meant for resource bundlers. It tells them to load the files together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The repository appears to be using Parcel. See
[Parcel's docs](https://parceljs.org/languages/css/) on CSS:

> Parcel includes support for CSS out of the box. To add a CSS file, either ... ... or import it from a JavaScript file:
>
> ```
> import './index.css';
> ```

What it will do is, if that JavaScript module is included, when the module is imported, it will insert the CSS (from that `./css/styles.css` path in the source code) onto the page. It's not a native JavaScript functionality of ES6 modules - it's something that a bundler (like Parcel, or Webpack, etc) manages. When bundling, the CSS text will be turned into a JavaScript string somewhere in the resulting bundle, and then put onto the page with something like

```
const style = document.createElement('style');
document.body.appendChild(style);
style.textContent = `<CONTENT OF IMPORTED CSS>`;
```